# Metadata/Elements in Views and Layouts

Tags: cakephp, model-view-controller, cakephp-3.0

I'm using CakePHP 3.x. I have just installed the source files and the first page that comes up uses the default.ctp layout which calls the home.ctp view. My understanding at the moment is that the view gets placed here in the layout,

```
 <?= $this->fetch('content') ?>
```

My question is, how come in both the view and the layout some elements and metadata are duplicated. So for instance both call

```
<?= $this->Html->charset() ?>
<?= $this->Html->meta('icon') ?>
```

and both duplicate the html structure by using `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>` tags.

To summarise, if i view the code of the webpage, lots of the structure is duplicated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

home.ctp on fresh installed cakephp is just example.

opet that file and see line 22

```
$this->layout = false;

if (!Configure::read('debug')):
    throw new NotFoundException('Please replace src/Template/Pages/home.ctp with your own version.');
endif;
```

As we see this home.ctp not use layout .ctp, simple clear all code from that file, and add for example:

```
<h1>This is my new landing page</h1>
```

save, reload, now your home.ctp use default.ctp layout with meta tags  etc..

Comment: I had deleted the `$this->layout = false;` line which is why it was duplicating everything. Thanks for the clarification.